# New relic requests vs views

Tags: newrelic

I get the newrelic performance emails every monday for an app. In that it says x number of requests. In another perf email about my other app it says y number of views. Now am confused between views and requests. Does anyone know the difference between views and requests?

App 1:
Response time: 84 ms
Requests 20 K
Uptime  99.75 %
Apdex   0.99

App 2:
Page load time  2.5s
Views   2390
Uptime  99.28%
Apdex  0.97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Page load time" refers to [Real User Monitoring](https://newrelic.com/docs/features/real-user-monitoring) time--the time it takes to render the entire page in the user's browser, from when the request is initiated until the Javascript onload event fires. Similarly, "Views" refers to pages loaded in a browser (that's executing JS).

"Response time" is the time spent only in the application server. It doesn't include browser rendering time, network transit time, or anything else outside your app code. "Requests" is the number of requests seen by your app server, including those that don't render a complete page (e.g., AJAX) or that aren't made by a browser.